# MYSQL Query for more condition

Tags: mysql

i have problem with my SQL query.
I have job table and job_feature. Now each Job object has many feature

**Example:** Job 1 has feature 1, 2, 9.
So now i need that query: `Select job has feature (1 or 2) and 9.` Advanced.
`Select job has feature (1 or 2 or 3) and (9 or 10)` and...
if using this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `m_job` as job
JOIN `d_job_feature` as jf ON job.id= jf.job_id
WHERE (jf.feature_id = 1 OR jf.feature_id = 2)
AND jf.feature_id = 9;
```

**=> return empty data**

So now, how can i using SQL for query this data.
Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is the `feature_id` for a given row cannot equal 1 or 2 and also 9.  Instead you need to group your features with `group by`.  Then you can use `condition aggregation` to see if both conditions can exist for a given feature.

Here's one option using `exists`:

```
select *
from m_job as m
where exists (
    select 1
    from d_job_feature as d
    where m.id=d.job_id
    group by d.job_id
    having max(case when d.feature_id in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and 
           max(case when d.feature_id in (9,10) then 1 else 0 end) = 1 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you join two queries?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SElECT`m_job` as job
JOIN `d_job_feature` as jf ON job.id= jf.job_id
WHERE jf.feature_id in(1,2,3)
) as t1 INNER JOIN
(
SELECT job.id
FROM `m_job` as job
JOIN `d_job_feature` as jf ON job.id= jf.job_id
WHERE jf.feature_id IN (9,10)
) as t2 ON t2.id ==t1.id
```

Comment: Thank Rio, i follow @sgeddes and it's work perfect. My Database has more feature. Example about query 'Select job has feature (1 or 2 or 3) and (9 or 10) AND (12 or 15) ...'. if using that Query, so it very complex

Comment: no problem. I would never have thought to do it like @sgeddes. love learning new things!  Good luck